# Flutter - How to proportionally center a view (centered with multiplier offset)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm wondering if in Flutter there are any good ways of imitating the iOS Xcode constraint where you center a view inside another (say, vertically), and supply a multiplier such that instead of being exactly centered (50% of the way down the parent view), it's positioned at 30% down, or 70% down, or whatever.

(Rather than use a fixed margin from the top of the screen, I'd like to "float" a header view down by 20% of the screen height...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All my `FractionallySizedBox` efforts have been unreliable, but here's a way that's proven far stabler for me - using `LayoutBuilder` and `SizedBox` as a spacer:

```
LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) => Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    SizedBox(height: (constraints.maxHeight - constraints.minHeight) * 0.2,),
    myWidget
  ],
))
```

This way `constraints` give me the ability to calculate 20% of the parent height, and apply that as a spacing using a simple SizedBox.

Answer (score 6):

[`FractionallySizedBox`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FractionallySizedBox-class.html) is enough by itself to handle such layout

```
FractionallySizedBox(
  heightFactor: .5,
  widthFactor: 1.0,
  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
  child: child,
)
```

This will top center a widget taking helf the height of its parent and full width

Comment: I'm afraid I can't get this to work - the Container child of this FractionallySizedBox is just filling the width and height of it...

Comment: Unless you mean, in the case of my example, use a FractionallySizedBox of 0.2 heightFactor, and then just use that as a spacer inside a column.. i.e. don't place the header view as its child, rather place it underneath..

Answer (score 3):

Set in container of parent view

Container(alignment: Alignment.center, ...)

Answer (score 2):

I found one way, but I'm not sure it's the neatest yet:

For vertical proportional centering:

Embed your layout inside a `Center` widget that is itself inside a  `FractionallySizedBox`. Provided that `FractionallySizedBox` is at the top of the screen, by changing its `heightFactor` you effectively change the centering position caused by the `Center` widget.

```
new FractionallySizedBox(
  heightFactor: someHeightFactor,
    child: Center(
      child: myChildWidget
    ),
);
```

i.e. if `parentHeight` = the height of the parent widget to this `FractionallySizedBox`, and `parentY` = the (absolute) y origin of that parent widget, then setting `heightFactor = 0.6` would center your UI child inside a region measuring `0.6 * parentHeight`, therefore with an absolute y center = `parentY + 0.3 * parentHeight`.

Horizontal proportional centering would be the same but using `widthFactor` on the `FractionallySizedBox`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `FractionallySizedBox` to size a widget relative to all available space, and wrap it with a `Container` or `Align` to specify the alignment of it.

For example:

```
Container(
  alignment: Alignment(0, -0.5),
  child: FractionallySizedBox(
    heightFactor: 0.5,
    widthFactor: 0.8,
    child: Container(color: Colors.blue),
  ),
)
```

This makes a blue box that's 50% of screen height and 80% of screen width, positioned at 25% down vertically.

[image]

Note, for the `Alignment` class, it takes in 2 parameters, for x and y axis alignment, ranges from -1 to +1. For example, (0,0) is center, (-1, -1) is top left corner, so here (0, -0.5) centers it horizontally and lifts it up half way vertically, resulting in 25% padding from the top.